# Is it possible to substitute a value for null in a sql server select statement?

Tags: sql-server, select

I am moving data from one table to another and I want a date field to change from null to a default value. What is the best way to do this in SQL Server(2000) ?

I want something similar to the IIf function in Access. 
Like IIF(DateBegin is null, #1/1/2000#,DateBegin)

Comment: What's the difference between ISNULL and COALESCE ? They both seem to work, but the isnull is easier for me to grock. Does one perform better? This was for a one-time query, but is there a case where it would be better ?

Comment: You can only use ISNULL with one value; COALESCE can be used with multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO destTable (dateColumn, otherColumn)
SELECT ISNULL(dateColumn, '2000-01-01'), otherColumn
FROM sourceTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the COALESCE operator in your select statement:

```
SELECT ..., COALESCE(datecolumn, 'default date') FROM SOURCE_TABLE
```

It returns the first non-null value.